# DOMPDF - Dynamic Layout Adjustment in Laravel PDF Invoice Generation

Tags: javascript, php, laravel, dompdf

Facing a challenge in my Laravel project using Dompdf for PDF invoices. I want the final amount table at the bottom, but here when there are fewer products, there's empty space between products table & final amount table. Need guidance or examples on making sure the products table stretched & filled with empty rows till final amount table & final amount stays at the bottom. Any help appreciated!

[this is pdf invoice generated using dompdf](https://i.stack.imgur.com/VSqjK.jpg)g

flexbox isn't supported in dompdf so is there any other way or other library where whether table has enough row or not but table filled till end of page automatically?

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Comment: DomPDF generates PDFs from HTML, which doesn't know about page height. There are PHP libraries that more directly create PDF files, like [FPDF](http://www.fpdf.org/) and then you can control the page layout exactly. It's more work than HTML though, and not as flexible. In this case I would say: Do you really need a border around everything?

Comment: @KIKOSoftware Yes. borders are part of invoice format.